# GeoTIFF: How to remove Internal Overview without recompression

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

"gdaladdo -clean" does not remove the internal overview from the file see http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4940

How do I remove GeoTIFF overview(s) without having to re-compress the main image.

Comment: Which version of gdaladdo are you using?

Comment: GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08

Comment: Think I may be able to self answer: tiffsplit (of libtiff, ubuntu package: libtiff-tools) and gdalcopyproj.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tiffsplit (of libtiff, debian/ubuntu package: libtiff-tools) and gdalcopyproj.py you can extract the main image + overviews and then copy across the original geo metadata.

Example:

```
tiffsplit source.tif tmp-
gdalcopyproj.py source.tif tmp-aaa.tif 
mv tmp-aaa.tif final.tif
rm tmp-???.tif
```